# Extract all words between two phrases using regex

Tags: php, regex, perl

I'm trying to extract all the words between two phrases using the following regex:

```
\b(?:item\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,2}?(?:1|one)\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,3}?business)\b(.*)\b(?:item\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,2}?(?:3|three)\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,3}?legal\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,3}?proceedings)\b
```

The documents I'm running this regex on are 10-K filings. The filings are too long to post here (see regex101 url below for example), but basically they are something like this:

```
ITEM 1. BUSINESS

lots of words

ITEM 2. PROPERTIES

lots of words

ITEM 3. LEGAL PROCEEDINGS
```

I want to extract all the words between `ITEM 1` and `ITEM 3`. Note that the subtitles for each ITEM may be slightly different for each 10-K filing, hence I'm allowing for a few words between each word.

I keep getting catastrophic backtracking error, and I cannot figure out why. For example, please see https://regex101.com/r/zgTiyb/1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your question is Unclear to me. Can you ask differently?  There is no `ITEM 1. BUSINESS` in your regex link.  Please be very precise about your input data and expected output.

Comment: @mickmackusa Yes there is: `Item 1.    Business` on line 323

Comment: Okay, I'll have a look in notepad.  (Google Chrome Find can't find that)  ...notepad couldn't either (tabbing)

Comment: And you want to stop matching at line 946?  ... that's a good sized chunk of characters.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. This is just one example 10-K, most are similar with slight difference in how they title ITEM 1, ITEM 2, ITEM 3, etc.

Comment: So you want the whole match captured as a single string eventhough `Item 2` will be in it?  Or is it better to divided the matches into `Item 1`'s text and `Item 2`'s text?  What is the next process for you in the project?  What are you doing with the string?

Comment: It can be divided or as one string, it doesn't matter. Divided may be better.

Comment: I will be running some textual analysis on the extracted string.

Comment: I'm still searching.  Here's food for thought: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8268624/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/18296441/2943403

Comment: Does the regex look fine to you? If so, then maybe that is the problem and I'll tackle this issue another way if regex won't work.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/zgTiyb/2, is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, that is perfect!

Comment: ...I don't know if I'd go as far to say "perfect"

Comment: That is true, but it is enough for me to try to finish it.

Comment: Relevant reading from Revo: [Catastrophic backtracking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39833391/2943403)

Comment: Thanks, looking into it because the regex Sebastian shared doesn't actually run in PHP for something reason (it runs just fine in regex101)...

Comment: Another educational page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27237579/simple-alphanumeric-regex-single-spacing-without-catastrophic-backtracking

Answer (score 3):

Catastrophic backtracking has almost one main reason:

> [A possible match is found but can't finish.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51149478/1020526)

You made too many positions available for regex to try. This hits backtracking limit on PCRE. A quick work around would be removing the only dot-star in regex in order to replace it with a restrictive quantifier i.e.

```
.{0,200}
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/3ips86/1)

But the better approach is re-constructing the regular expression:

```
\bitem\b.*?\b(?:1|one)\b(*COMMIT)\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,2}?business\b\h*\R+(?:(?!item\h+(?:3|three)\b)[\s\S])*+item\h+(?:3|three)\b\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,3}?legal\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,3}?proceedings\b
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/JdYtgK/1)

Your own regex needs ~45K steps on given input string to find those two matches. In contrast, this modified regex needs ~8K steps to accomplish the task. That's a huge improvement.

The latter doesn't need `s` flag (and it shouldn't be enabled). I used `(*COMMIT)` backtracking verb to cause an early failure if a possible match is found but is likely to not finish.

@[Sebastian Proske](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51146655/1020526)'s solution matches three sub-strings but I don't think the third match is an expected match. This huge third match is the only reason for your regex to break.

Please [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50511784/1020526) to have a better insight into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really catastrophic backtracking, just a whole lot of text and a comparedly low backtracking limit in regex101. In this scenario the use of `.*` isn't optimal, as it will match the whole remainder of the textfile once it is reached and then backtrack character after character to match the parts after it - which means a lot of characters to process.

Seems you can stick to `\w+\W+` at that place as well and use lazy matching instead of greedy to get your result, like

[`\b(?:item\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,2}?(?:1|one)\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,3}?business)\b\W+(?:\w+\W+)*?\b(?:item\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,2}?(?:3|three)\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,3}?legal\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,3}?proceedings)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/zgTiyb/2)

Note that the pcre engine optimizes `(?:\w+\W+)` to `(?>\w++\W++)` thus working by word-no-word-chunks instead of single characters.

Comment: FYI, while this code works in regex101, it crashes in PHP.